# Changing a String decimal (2.9) to Int or Long issues

Tags: java

Okay, I'm fairly new to java but I'm learning quickly(hopefully). So anyway here is my problem:

I have a string(For example we will use 2.9), I need to change this to either int or long or something similar that I can use to compare to another number.

As far as I know int doesn't support decimals, I'm not sure if long does either? If not I need to know what does support decimals.

This is the error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2.9"` with both Interger.parseInt and Long.parseLong

So any help would be appreciated!

Comment: An integer is a number that can be written without a fractional or decimal component https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `int` and `long` are integer values (being `long` the representation of a *long integer* that is an integer with a higher capacity). The parsing fails because those types do not support a decimal part.

If you were to use them and enforce a casting you're relinquishing the decimal part of the number.

```
double iAmADouble = 100 / 3;
int iWasADouble = (int)iAmADouble; //This number turns out to be 33
```

Use `double` or `float` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can't directly get `int` (or) `long` from decimal point value.

One approach is:

First get a double value and then get  int (or) long.

Example:

```
int temp =  Double.valueOf("20.2").intValue();
System.out.println(temp);
```

output:

```
20
```

Comment: Or, better, `(int)Double.parseDouble("20.2")` so as to avoid creating a throw-away Double object.

Answer (score 4):

`int` and `long` are both integer datatypes, 32-bit and 64-bit respectively. You can use `float` or `double` to represent floating point numbers.

Answer (score 3):

That string (2.9) is neither `integer` nor `long`. You should use some decimal point types, for example `float` or `double`.